Solving non-linear recursion with linear and exponential terms
I encountered the recursion $$\frac{a[n+2]}{a[n+1]}-e^{-\frac{a[n+1]}{a[n]}}=0$$ when trying to explain why points are apparently arranged along an exponential curve in the scatter plot of an empiric dataset depicted in the image below.
I am however interested in methods for solving the recursion itself, or more generally recursions with a functional dependency of $\frac{a[n+2]}{a[n+1]}$ on $\frac{a[n+1]}{a[n]}$
I know that generating functions may help, but would appreciate concrete steps for their application to the above recursion.


If you look at $b(n) = \frac{a(n+1)}{a(n)}$ you get $b(n) = \exp_{1/e}^n(b(0))$ — tetration.

This should converge quite quickly to the omega constant $\Omega$ (which is the fixed point of $e^{-x}$), so you can expect $a(n)$ to be proportional to $\Omega^n$

@CommandMaster could you please elaborate a bit on the tetration expression in your first comment, resp. where can I find an explanation of the notation?

$b(n)$ satisfies $b(n+1)=(1/e)^{b(n)}$, so $b(n) = (1/e)^{(1/e)^{\dots^{b(0)}}}$ with $n$ exponentiations. This is exactly tetration, which you can read about on Wikipedia

Please state what the axes of the plot represent.
